# Access $key of an object within a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, foreach

Since I started to write more code in OOP I always run into a in my point of view "code styling" problem. I want to add some additional data to an existing object. When I used arrays this was easily possible with foreach because every array item got its own key. Now with objects I didn't found a way how I can access each item with an key.

```
$data_items = $this->model->get_function();
$data_items = (array) $data_items;
foreach ($data_items as $key => $row)
{
      $data_items[$key]['additional_data'] = 'additional_data';                      
}
$data_items = (object) $data_items;
```

I think my code is only a work around. Can please somebody tell me if I can get rid off the code line "$data_items = (array) $data_items;" and "$data_items = (object) $data_items;".

**Thanks to everybody who replied to my question!**

Until now I didn't realized that it is so easy what I tried to achieve:

```
foreach ($data_items as $row)
{
    $row->additional_data = 'additional_data';
}
```

Comment: ArrayAccess interface for your objects. http://php.net/arrayaccess

Comment: What's preventing you from doing `foreach` directly on the object?

Comment: Since you are not trying to cast object to string or integer without magic method, you can loop through the object

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php - "foreach works only on arrays and objects"

Comment: oop is great, but using php stdclass objects offers none of oops benefits. in php, you should always favor regular arrays over stdclass objects when storing a collection of values, simply because the language provides the best support for arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects and arrays look pretty much the same from the viewpoint of data handling. You can simply add another object property and save your data to it without having to declare said property (in my opinion, it's a drawback, but in your case - an advantage).

Array:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['additional_data'] = 'foo';
```

Object:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->additional_data = 'bar';
```

Foreach will handle object properties just the same as it will handle array keys.
And no need for implicit casting.

Here's the cast-free variant:

```
$data_items = $this->model->get_function();
foreach ($resource_contacts as $key => $row)
{
      // Note, $data_items->{$key} must be an object, or this will crash.
      // You can check if it is with is_object() and react accordingly
      $data_items->{$key}->additional_data = 'additional_data';                      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the object implements the `Traversable` interface (`ArrayAccess`, `Iterable`), like the `stdClass`, you can easily `foreach` the instance:

```
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->bar = 'foobar';
foreach($foo as $property => $value)
{
    echo '$foo->'.$property.' === '.$value;
    echo $foo->{$property} = 'reassign';
}
```

Without implementing these interfaces, you'll still be able to iterate over any object, however: only the public properties will be visible. 
To get around this, I tend to declare all my properties as protected, and have all my data objects inherit from an abstract model, that implements the `Iterator` interface, so I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Curious. I've been using my own classes quite a bit and never had to implicitly state that they implement any of these properties. Foreach just worked. Is there some bigger picture I'm missing?

Comment: but isn't the author trying to foreach a method, which we don't know what returns

Comment: @MaximKumpan: Implicit iteration only allows access to the public properties

Comment: @RoyalBg: The OP wants to get rif of the casts, if he's not using PHP5.4+, there's no alternative to assigning the return value to a tmp var.

Comment: It's inside a class. But let's say it's: `$a = new Class(); $b = $a->method()` should $b get instance of stdClass in order to do foreach on it?

Comment: @RoyalBg: No: `stdClass`, `$b instanceof Traversable`, `is_array($b)` will all work. Even `is_object($b)`, but in the last case, you'll only iterate over the public properties, like I said

Comment: So it depends on how `method()` is done, or maybe I missunderstood again. Sorry. Is it an universal solution? I mean, my class/object needs to implement the interfare, otherwise there's no universal way to loop through the methods

Comment: @RoyalBg: looping through the _methods_ can be acchieved by `get_class_methods`, or (depending on what you need) by implementing the magic `__call` method

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$data_items = $this->model->get_function();
foreach ($resource_contacts as $key => $row)
{
      $data_items->$key->additional_data = 'additional_data';                      
}
```

Comment: `additional_data` is not a variable in the original question.

Comment: `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: additional_data in php shell code on line 4`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've removed the extra '$' now, I guess I wasn't really paying attention. OP has solved his problem now, so I guess my fix is a bit redundant now...

Answer (score 0):

Use references to be able to modify your object inside the `foreach` loop, if that is what you are trying to achieve:

```
foreach($objectList as &$obj){
    $obj->newProperty = 'whatever';
}
```